# What is the Operator Precedence of Await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, operator-precedence

In Javascript certain operators are processed before others:

```
1 + 2 * 3
// 1 + (2 * 3)
// 7 because * has higher precedence than +

1 === 0 + 1
// 1 === (0 + 1)
// true because + has a higher precedence than ===
```

The MDN has a [full breakdown of all operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and their precedence ... except `await`:

```
await getFoo() * 2; // await (getFoo() * 2) or (await getFoo()) * 2?
await getFoo() === 5; // await (getFoo() === 5) or (await getFoo()) === 5?
```

(**EDIT:** The MDN *does* include `await` now; it didn't when I originally wrote this question.)

Can anyone explain which operators are processed before/after await?

Right now I feel like I have to add a bunch of parenthesis that are probably unnecessary because I'm not sure what will get handled before/after `await`.  And while I know I should just be able to look this up, even MDN (the gold standard of documentation IMHO) doesn't have the answer.

Comment: Interesting. `await` expects an expression after, but gives no clues as to how precedence is handled. Time to experiment.

Comment: My understanding is that `await` is treated in the same way as any unary operator.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An [*AwaitExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-AwaitExpression) is a [*UnaryExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression) and has the same precedence as `delete`, `void`, `typeof`, `+`, `-`, `~`, and `!`, binding stronger than any binary operator.

This is unlike `yield` which has a precedence lower than anything else except the comma operator. This [design decision](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/precedence-of-yield-operator) was made because both `yield a+b` and `await a + await b` are scenarios thought to be more common than `(yield a) + (yield b)` and `await (a + b)`.

Comment: I also fixed MDN :-)

Comment: For operators such as `+`, this makes perfect sense, however, one major pitfall is the use of `&&` with `await`. Consider `await url && fetch(url)`. If `url` is falsy here, we will short-circuit and return the value of `url` (so, typically `undefined`) - that's intended - but if it's truthy, we will proceed to call `fetch(url)` but the expression returns the _promise_ for the fetch call, not the _resolved value_. What you want here is most likely `await (url && fetch(url))`.

Comment: Then again, in most cases `url && await fetch(url)` will do just fine. :)

Comment: @JHH I tend to avoid `await`ing non-thenables in general on principle, since it tends to produce code that's confusing to read, as you have so kindly demonstrated ;)

Comment: The answer doesn't make clear what operators are preceding `await`. Dot (.) operator has higher priority than `await`. If you have an `async` function called `func` and it returns the object `{prop: 'str'}`, you would have to write `(await func()).prop` to get the property correctly, otherwise `await func().prop` will return `undefined`.

Comment: @Kutalia I'm not going to reproduce the [entire operator table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) in this answer, but yes member access is one of the operators with higher precedence than the unary operators.

Comment: @Kutalia it does work actually and doesn't yield undefined https://jsfiddle.net/46a3y8mj/ . I think you've meant `function f(){
  return Promise.resolve({p:'sdf'});
}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to clarify a specific use case that brought me to this question today. The accepted answer and MDN's documentation would imply this but I figured I'd share...

I have an `async` function that returns an object. When the function resolves I want to refer to one of that object's attributes.

```js
await foo().name
```

**My question was:**

> In which order do the following three things take place: The function invocation, `await`, and the attribute lookup.

I briefly experimented to learn the following...

```js
async function foo() {
    return { name: "John" };
}

async function main() {
    const returnValue = foo();
    const attributeValue = returnValue.name;

    let undefinedVariable;

    console.log("returnValue:", returnValue);
    console.log("attributeValue:", attributeValue);

    console.log("");

    console.log("await foo().name:", await foo().name);

    console.log("await undefined:", await undefined);
    console.log("await undefinedVariable:", await undefinedVariable);

    console.log("");

    console.log("(await foo()).name:", (await foo()).name);
}

main();
```

**Result:**

```js
returnValue: Promise { { name: 'John' } }
attributeValue: undefined

await foo().name: undefined
await undefined: undefined
await undefinedVariable: undefined

(await foo()).name: John
```

**Lesson:**

Without mitigation (parentheses), the order-of-operations is:

1. The function is invoked

   - Returning a `Promise`
2. The attribute is looked-up

   - Evaluating to `undefined` because the `Promise` object doesn't possess the attribute "name"
3. Finally, `await` is performed

   - Evaluating to `undefined` because `await`ing `undefined` returns `undefined`

In order to get what I wanted, I needed to force `await` to act on the return value of the function and **then** read the resultant object's "name" attribute.

```js
(await foo()).name
```

I hope this more precisely applies to someone's use case.

Comment: Fo reference, this is noted in [a comment on Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218744/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-await#comment122594563_48218807).