# is associativity and precedence a standard or implementation specific to plateform ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**context** :
the starting point is a simple question i asked myself : 
why ``` typeof '' === typeof "" === typeof `` ``` is false ? Shortly after, i found the answer but that lead me to the subject of precedence and associativity.

MDN gives us the table : precedence order ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)) and associativity for JavaScript.
But i'm not sur on which source MDN based his table. So i started to search : 
firstly i read the specification from ECMA website, but did not find any reference to associativity or precedence. ([ES 8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/), [Javascript 1.0](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) (*it's a pdf*))

So i search on StackOverflow for answered questions and found some but most of all are pointing to MDN table. One of those [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218744/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-await) lead me to [esdiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/) but again, can't find the source of what define the associativity and precedence of an operator precisely.

So i'm here to cary on my research :

**Question :** 
Is precedence and associativity defined in the ES standard or related to the implementation (Node, ff, chrome etc)?
In the case of it is a standard, can you point me the spot i missed ?
In the case that it is related to the implementation, what defined the order of precedence ?

thanks.

Comment: It looks like precedence are beeing discussed in the TC39 github issues (https://github.com/search?q=org%3Atc39+precedence&type=Issues) so it should be a global behavior defined in the specs.

Comment: The standards are rather hard to read. They are not written as specifications like the C standard which would allow one to understand a language feature. Rather, the standards for ECMAscript is written from the point of view of telling someone how they can implement an interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, operator precedence and associativity is governed by the ECMAScript specification. It is not spelled out in a table like MDN does it, but rather an implicit property of the grammar (how the productions are nested).