# Using an await in function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Is it possible to use await with a parameter? for example:

```
const run = async () => {
  getStudentDetails(await getStudentId());
}
```

Even if it is, it seems like it might not be the best idea. Anyone done this before?

Comment: Thats the best idea ever, I'm doing that all the time, thats what `await` is good for!

Comment: Just be to sure to handle promise (await) rejections...

Comment: @CodyG.  and how does one handle promise (await) rejections?

Comment: i've done it: `var pw=this.parseHex(await this.derive(password));`

Comment: `const run = async () => {
  try{getStudentDetails(await getStudentId());}catch(e){ //Do something when getSTudentId() fails}
}`

Comment: the proposed `do` block will allow inline handling of errors...

Comment: Hmmm. New question: what happens when you call something like `foo(await bar1(), await bar2())` ? I assume `bar2` waits until `bar1` but I'm too lazy to try and have never used that syntax

Comment: aside: it's in the argument, not the parameter...

Comment: Yeah never used that syntax either. Honestly the more I think about it is probably kinda dangerous. As there is not an easy way to handle errors, and hard to read. Probably better to define it before running function.

Comment: @CodyＧfoo(await bar1(), await bar2()) will not work in parallel. I wrote an answer how to do in a best way

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use `await` expressions in every arbitrary context ([where it parses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218807/1048572)) inside the `async function`, including as arguments to function calls. There's nothing wrong with it.

It's equivalent to

```
const run = async () => {
  const studentId = await getStudentId();
  getStudentDetails(studentId);
}
```

Comment: And as long as you are in the same calling context as the async function, e.g. this doesn't work: `async () => fnTakingCb(() => await getStudentId());`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, that's not in the async function, that's in the arrow function callback.

Answer (score 5):

I do it all the time. However in case if you want to pass more than one parameter to function they will be resolved sequentially. To fight that problem I wrote an util function which looks like that:

```
async function call(func, ...args) {
    return func(...await Promise.all(args));
}

(async function() {
        console.log(await call(functionToCall, delay(2000), delay(2000)));
})();
```

With that syntax functionToCall will be called in 2 seconds instead of 4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will work, as you can use the `await` keyword everywhere where you can use an expression.

However, I'd prefer a slightly updated version of your code for better readability (and for better debugability, too):

```
const run = async () => {
  const studentId = await getStudentId();

  getStudentDetails(studentId);
}
```

I hope this helps