# Can not use 'yield' as identifier inside a generator

Tags: javascript, syntax, language-lawyer, generator, ecmascript-2018

While composing an [async generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Iterating_over_async_generators) function, I noticed that the following construct results in a `SyntaxError`:

```
async function * foo() {
  await yield bar; // Can not use 'yield' as identifier inside a generator
}
```

Even though reversing the order of the contextual keywords is perfectly acceptable:

```
async function * foo() {
  yield await bar; // OK
}
```

After reading the error carefully, I was able to correct the syntax by wrapping the `UnaryExpression` within the `AwaitExpression` in parentheses to avoid parsing the token `yield` as an identifier instead of a contextual keyword:

```
async function * foo() {
  await (yield bar); // OK
}
```

But this begs the question, what specific static semantics in [ECMAScript 2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/) are involved that cause `yield` to be parsed as an identifier in this context, while `await` does not require special treatment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of [precedence of the `await` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218744/1048572), which [forms a `UnaryExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#prod-UnaryExpression) (and has one as its operand), unlike the `yield` operator which [forms an `AssignmentExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression) (and has one as its optional operand). An `AssignmentExpression` does not form a `UnaryExpression`, which means that you simply are not allowed to nest them like that.

When the `await` expression is parsed, the next token fed to the parse is used to form a `UnaryExpression`, and the only choice for `yield` to do that is as an `IdentifierReference` (totally ignoring the `bar` that follows after it). Of course in a generator parsing context that is not allowed, leading to the confusing error message.

Notice that both forms of nesting (`await (yield …)` and `yield (await …)`) are totally unnecessary anyway, as the `yield` keyword in an asynchronous generator function already does await both the yielded value and the resumption value [internally](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-asyncgeneratoryield), so you should just omit the `await` keyword and use only `yield`.